# Android Connect to GSMcomm

Tags: c#, android, gsmcomm

I am trying to use my android version 4.1.1 as a GSM modem but the error "No phone connected" always comes out. I tried using many Baud rate and timeout combinations but doesn't work.

I connected my phone through USB, is this correct? Or I need to use other connections?

Comment: Connecting phone through USB is not correct. You should try RS232-to-USB

Comment: Thats what I'm seeing in the other forums. But I'm confused, how can I connect my phone through that adapter if it does not contain the thin something thats needed to be plugged on my phone?

Comment: Different cables are available in the market but, before purchasing make sure they will work. [http://www.pcables.com/] [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Micro-Serial-Adapter-Android/dp/B00KXQUGXM]

Comment: What type of phone will surely work?

Answer (score 0):

Not all phones support the modem interface for sending and receiving SMS messages. In particular, most smart phones, including Blackberries, iPhone, and Windows Mobile devices, do not support this GSM modem interface for sending and receiving SMS messages at all. Additionally, Nokia phones that use the S60 (Series 60) interface, which is Symbian based, only support sending SMS messages via the modem interface, and do not support receiving SMS via the modem interface.

Comment: So what phones those support sending SMS messages via the modem interface, and receiving SMS via the modem interface ?